# RasGetEntryProperties returning all zeroes

Tags: c#, pinvoke, ras

I am trying to get information about one of my Phonebook entries using `RasGetEntryProperties` but when I do, the RASENTRY struct that returns contains zeroes or blanks for all elements except for `dwSize` and `dwOptions`.

I don't have a full understanding of how this data works but I would have thought I'd at least see the device name or phone number which is stored in the phonebook...

Here is my code:

```
        uint dwEntryInfoSize = 0;
        uint i = RasGetEntryProperties(null, "", IntPtr.Zero, ref dwEntryInfoSize, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);


        RASENTRY getRasEntry = new RASENTRY();
        string entryName = "Dial-up Connection test";
        getRasEntry.dwSize = (int)dwEntryInfoSize;

        IntPtr ptrRasEntry = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)dwEntryInfoSize);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(getRasEntry, ptrRasEntry, false);

        uint j = RasGetEntryProperties(null, entryName, ptrRasEntry, ref dwEntryInfoSize, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

        RASENTRY outRasEntry = (RASENTRY)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptrRasEntry, typeof(RASENTRY));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrRasEntry);
```

[image: Phonebook entry properties]

And here is a partial screenshot of `outRasEntry` in the Watch in Visual Studio debugger...

[image: Output in debugger watch]

**EDIT**
Here is my definition of `RASENTRY`

```
    const int MAX_PATH = 260;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RASENTRY
    {
          public int       dwSize;
          public int       dwfOptions;
          public int       dwCountryID;
          public int       dwCountryCode;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) RasFieldSizeConstants.RAS_MaxAreaCode+1)]
          public string       szAreaCode;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) RasFieldSizeConstants.RAS_MaxPhoneNumber+1)]
          public string       szLocalPhoneNumber;
          public int       dwAlternateOffset;
          public RASIPADDR   ipaddr;
          public RASIPADDR   ipaddrDns;
          public RASIPADDR   ipaddrDnsAlt;
          public RASIPADDR   ipaddrWins;
          public RASIPADDR   ipaddrWinsAlt;
          public int       dwFrameSize;
          public int       dwfNetProtocols;
          public int       dwFramingProtocol;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) MAX_PATH)]
          public string       szScript;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) MAX_PATH)]
          public string       szAutodialDll;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) MAX_PATH)]
          public string       szAutodialFunc;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) RasFieldSizeConstants.RAS_MaxDeviceType + 1)]
          public string       szDeviceType;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) RasFieldSizeConstants.RAS_MaxDeviceName + 1)]
          public string       szDeviceName;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) RasFieldSizeConstants.RAS_MaxPadType + 1)]
          public string       szX25PadType;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) RasFieldSizeConstants.RAS_MaxX25Address + 1)]
          public string       szX25Address;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) RasFieldSizeConstants.RAS_MaxFacilities + 1)]
          public string       szX25Facilities;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) RasFieldSizeConstants.RAS_MaxUserData + 1)]
          public string       szX25UserData;
          public int       dwChannels;
          public int       dwReserved1;
          public int       dwReserved2;
          public int       dwSubEntries;
          public int       dwDialMode;
          public int       dwDialExtraPercent;
          public int       dwDialExtraSampleSeconds;
          public int       dwHangUpExtraPercent;
          public int       dwHangUpExtraSampleSeconds;
          public int       dwIdleDisconnectSeconds;
          public int       dwType;
          public int       dwEncryptionType;
          public int       dwCustomAuthKey;
          public Guid        guidId;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) MAX_PATH)]
          public string       szCustomDialDll;
          public int       dwVpnStrategy;
          public int       dwfOptions2;
          public int       dwfOptions3;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) RasFieldSizeConstants.RAS_MaxDnsSuffix)]
          public string       szDnsSuffix;
          public int       dwTcpWindowSize;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) MAX_PATH)]
          public string       szPrerequisitePbk;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst =
                (int) RasFieldSizeConstants.RAS_MaxEntryName)]
          public string       szPrerequisiteEntry;
          public int       dwRedialCount;
          public int       dwRedialPause;
          RASIPV6ADDR ipv6addrDns;
          RASIPV6ADDR ipv6addrDnsAlt;
          public int       dwIPv4InterfaceMetric;
          public int       dwIPv6InterfaceMetric;
          RASIPV6ADDR ipv6addr;
          public int       dwIPv6PrefixLength;
          public int       dwNetworkOutageTime;
    }

public enum RasFieldSizeConstants
{
    RAS_MaxDeviceType = 16,
    RAS_MaxPhoneNumber = 128,
    RAS_MaxIpAddress = 15,
    RAS_MaxIpxAddress = 21,
    RAS_MaxEntryName = 256,
    RAS_MaxDeviceName = 128,
    RAS_MaxCallbackNumber = RAS_MaxPhoneNumber,
    RAS_MaxAreaCode = 10,
    RAS_MaxPadType = 32,
    RAS_MaxX25Address = 200,
    RAS_MaxFacilities = 200,
    RAS_MaxUserData = 200,
    RAS_MaxReplyMessage = 1024,
    RAS_MaxDnsSuffix = 256,
    UNLEN = 256,
    PWLEN = 256,
    DNLEN = 15
}

    public struct RASIPADDR {
        byte a;
        byte b;
        byte c;
        byte d;
    }

    public struct RASIPV6ADDR
    {
        byte a;
        byte b;
        byte c;
        byte d;
        byte e;
        byte f;
    }
```

Comment: You should probably read the docs, show us the definition of `RASENTRY` and mention the return values you get from calling `RasGetEntryProperties`. Also line 2 and 3 seems to not even being used. Also: Why not use an existing library such as http://dotras.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: I've posted the definition of RASENTRY and removed lines 2 & 3 (they were left over from earlier attempts to get things to work).
The `dwfOptions` would appear to be correct from looking at some of the properties in Windows so I believe it's finding the right entry, but even the Guid is zeroes... I will check out that library. Also, I have read the MSDN docs and looked on pinvoke.net - if you could point me to any better documentation than this, it would be appreciated!

Comment: I had a look at that library and it looks very well done. I would not go through the pain of having to recreate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks leppie for pointing me in the direction of dotras.codeplex.com - although I didn't end up using that library, looking at its source code helped me fix my own...

The key was in the definition of `RASENTRY`... The change in the first line below made it work

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 4)]
public struct RASENTRY
{
    public int       dwSize;
    public int       dwfOptions;
    public int       dwCountryID;
    public int       dwCountryCode;

// etc.
```